# "sf::Unicode::Text::text" member function already defined or declared

Tags: c++, qt-creator, sfml

I've recently managed to set up SFML for qt creator however upon compilation of the code bellow, I get three strange errors which have nothing to do with my program. I must specify other C++ programs run fine. This is the code:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::Clock Clock;
    while (Clock.GetElapsedTime() < 5.f)
    {
        std::cout << Clock.GetElapsedTime() << std::endl;
        sf::Sleep(0.5f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The errors are as follows:

```
f:\SFML-1.6\include\SFML\System\Unicode.hpp:82: error: C2535: 'sf::Unicode::Text::Text(const wchar_t *)' : member function already defined or declared

f:\SFML-1.6\include\SFML\System\Unicode.hpp:87: error: C2535: 'sf::Unicode::Text::Text(const std::wstring &)' : member function already defined or declared

f:\SFML-1.6\include\SFML\System\Unicode.hpp:99: error: C2535: 'sf::Unicode::Text::operator std::wstring(void) const' : member function already defined or declared
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

**EDIT:**

I should also mention I never touched the files which give the errors. All I tried was to paste the sample code from the SFML website which resulted in the errors above. I believe I've set up SFML correctly.

**EDIT2:**
I'm using Windows XP SP3, Mingw compiler

Comment: No idea, but usually I would look at the pre-processed version of the source (myfile.cpp). Usually the option is -E, but might differ based on compiler. something like: `CC -E <other options> my.cpp > preprocessed.cpp`, --edit-- you would need to use all other cmd line opts passed to CC normally.

Comment: According to [source code](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.4/Unicode_8hpp_source.php), the most probable reason is that somewhere you have `typedef wchar_t Unit16`, or `typedef Uint16 wchar_t`

Comment: @Lol4t0, That's impossible I didn't even touch it, but I will take a look.

Comment: @It may depend on config and system headers.

Comment: Given that you're combining this with Qt, I seem to recall that this might be caused by your Qt configuration. That is, there probably is a Zc:wchar_t option enabled in your qmake.conf... Perhaps that gives you some Google-fu already.

Comment: @Bart Thanks, that's very useful and I'll further research this problem, I love Qt and developing things just seems easier on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the problem a long time ago, the only solution and explanation that worked for me (Copying from another forum post that I originally consulted):

> QMake sets the compiler option `treat wchar_t as a built-in type` to
>   `false`, making `wchar_t` a typedef to `unsigned short`, which makes
>   functions overloaded for both `unsigned short` and `wchar_t` (like the
>   `sf::Unicode::Text` constructor) fail...
>
> I think the only solution, other than modifying SFML sources, is to
>   change the option "Zc:wchar_t" to "-Zc:wchar_t" in your
>   \mkspecs\win32-msvc2008\qmake.conf file. And then probably
>   recompile Qt.

I changed my configuration file and recompiled qt and it has started working as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

If /Zc:wchar_t- is specified, the compiler requires you to either define wchar_t or to include one of the many header files that defines it (for example, wchar.h). Typically, **wchar_t is defined as an unsigned short**.

To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment

```
Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Modifying Project Settings.

Click the C/C++ folder.

Click the Language property page.

Modify the Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type property.
```

So the problem is that in Config.hpp

```
typedef unsigned short Uint16;
```

and with this  /Zc:wchar_t option wchar_t is

```
typedef unsigned short wchar_t;
```

so they are equals

Comment: Any idea how to set that in qt creator?

Comment: @ThePlan in my time, i had done it with a flag for g++. Searching now for it.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521252/qt-msvc-and-zcwchar-t-i-want-to-blow-up-the-world
it is a bug
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-6345

Comment: @ThePlan It looks like It's a bug for QT not using built-in wchar_t. What is your compiler and OS by the way, so we can give better solutions to you.

Comment: I am running the windows XP SP3 and using Mingw

Comment: @ThePlan if you think you can do it, try my answer content, that is: change zc:wchar_t status and recompile qt from source.

Comment: @Seçkin Savaşçı, I tried but it seems rather complicated, and it lead to 50 different errors so I rolled it back, but I haven't had a chance to try out the other answers because of another question I posted which dazzled me. I never thought setting sfml for qt creator would be so hard :(

Comment: @Back then, I faced this error on my ubuntu while using gcc. So I have no clue about your errors and possible solutions for them. I think we hit the wall hard here. Maybe another one can help you.